# javascript show &quot; instead of double quots

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, charts

I want to show a line chart in my page by javascript.
sample code for showing chart is same as below

```
new Chartist.Line('#chart-with-area', {
  labels: ["d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5", "d6", "d7", "d8"],
  series: [
    [5, 9, 7, 8, 5, 3, 5, 4]
  ]
}, {
  low: 0,
  showArea: true,
  plugins: [
    Chartist.plugins.tooltip()
  ]
});
```

I am using laravel framework and I need to send data from php to javascript.

I created two arrays, one for labels and one for data.

The problem is that when I add array for labels , I faced with below errors

**htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given**

and when I send json , javascript change double quots

```
new Chartist.Line('#chart-with-area', {
                labels: [&quot;2021\/7\/5&quot;,&quot;2018\/11\/17&quot;,&quot;2019\/1\/8&quot;,&quot;2018\/10\/25&quot;,&quot;2019\/4\/9&quot;,&quot;2018\/11\/18&quot;,&quot;2019\/3\/11&quot;,&quot;2019\/1\/3&quot;,&quot;2019\/1\/5&quot;,&quot;2018\/12\/17&quot;,&quot;2021\/5\/25&quot;,&quot;2018\/12\/31&quot;],
                series: [[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,2,6]]
            }, {
                low: 0,
                showArea: true,
                plugins: [
                    Chartist.plugins.tooltip()
                ]
            });
```

here is my code:

```
new Chartist.Line('#chart-with-area', {
            labels: {{json_encode($requestLineChartLabel)}},
            series: [{{json_encode($requestLineChartData,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)}}]
        }, {
            low: 0,
            showArea: true,
            plugins: [
                Chartist.plugins.tooltip()
            ]
        });
```

I searched a lot, but can't find any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Laravel 7 or higher, you can use the @json blade directive to properly output json:

```
labels: @json($requestLineChartLabel),
series: [@json($requestLineChartData,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)]
```

Just make sure that those variables are not already json, or else you'll be double encoding it.